# Why typescript throws an error for two array of object types but doesn't on shape of both?

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, javascript-objects

I have two simple types of data:

```
type IData = {
  percent: string;
  exchange: string;
};

type IRow = {
  price: number;
  exchange: string;
};
```

I'm not following why typescript throws errors here if I use them both:

```
const sumSame = (
  assets: IData[] | IRow[],
  sumBy: string,
  sumWhat: string
) => {
  const mapWithUniqCoins = assets.reduce((accMap, el: IData | IRow) => {
    if (accMap.has(el[sumBy])) {
      accMap.set(el[sumBy], {
        ...accMap.get(el[sumBy]),
        [sumWhat]: accMap.get(el[sumBy])[sumWhat] =
          +accMap.get(el[sumBy])[sumWhat] + parseFloat(el[sumWhat])
      });
    } else {
      accMap.set(el[sumBy], el);
    }

    return accMap;
  }, new Map());

  return [...mapWithUniqCoins.values()];
};
```

But it doesn't throw errors when I combine two types into one shape:

```
type Shape = IData | IRow;
```

Why it happened?
https://codesandbox.io/s/16vzvqqv3 (Check Errors.ts and NoErrors.ts)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When `assets` are declared as a union of arrays

```
assets: IData[] | IRow[]
```

`assets.reduce()` has different declarations in each array type: for `IData[]` array, `reduce()` takes a callback that receives `IData` element, for `IRow[]` array, `reduce()` takes a callback that receives `IRow` element.

The error message - "Cannot invoke an expression whose type lacks a call signature" - is basically telling that the compiles is not smart enough to recognize that it could be possible to call `reduce()` for the union type, even when it receives appropriate callback type.

[There is open issue for this](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7294):

> This is currently by design because we don't synthesize an
>   intersectional call signature when getting the members of a union type
>   -- only call signatures which are identical appear on the unioned type